# Grails Spring Security interceptUrlMap: how to restrict access of index.gsp

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

When I call to any action of testcontroller, it redirects to the login page. I want when I go to my homepage (index.gsp), it also redirect to the login page. I tried:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/index.gsp': ["isAuthenticated()"],
    '/testcontroller/**': ["isAuthenticated()"]
]
```

But it does not work. Why? How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/testcontroller/**': ["isAuthenticated()"],
    '/*':                 ["isAuthenticated()"]
]
```

This is stricter. Authenticates non-anonymous user from anonymous user at the root context.
Should this work?